# Android equivilent of ios message://

Tags: android, custom-protocol

Using custom uri protocols in both iOS and Android we can open default apps from our own apps. For example to open the default maps app iOS gives us `maps://` and on Android we have `geo://`.

I want to open the default mail client on each. For the default mail app iOS gives us `message://` but does anyone know what the Android equivalent would be to open the default mail app.

(I've tried 'mailto://' but on both platforms this starts a new email, rather than just launching the mail app)

Thanks.

EDIT: INTENTS are not an option, i need to use a URI scheme.

Comment: The thing is that protocol is use to receive specific action, not just start an application. `geo` is used to show a location (using the parameters), `mailto` is use to send a mail to a adress, also using the parameters. It is not simple made to start an app to the home page. For that, you need to send an intent...

Answer (score 3):

> Using custom uri protocols in both iOS and Android we can open default apps from our own apps

Only in selected scenarios. That approach is generally frowned upon in Android.

> and on Android we have geo://

Note that `geo:` does not use slashes.

> what the Android equivalent would be to open the default mail app

There is no URL scheme that will open a mail app, other than `mailto:`, which as you note is for composing a message.

If you are writing a native Android app, you can follow the instructions in [the documentation for `CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_EMAIL) to attempt to open an email app. Note that not all email apps will necessarily support this `Intent` structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use intent in Android to open apps for specific tasks

Please check out the documentation below

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

for mails specifically

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Email

Comment: Thanks for your response, but unfortunately I am constrained to using a protocol rather than an intent.

Comment: @gingerbreadboy most welcome , I wanted to help but out of intents my knowledge is limited in this topic , hope someone can help you soon

Comment: Why are intents not an option? just check the url for the iOS `message://` and launch an intent for email

Comment: because of framework restrictions (which I have no control over) I am forced to use a third party plugin which will only accept a uri protocol.